# Why an old value of an smart-contract property is retrieved instead of the most current one?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I've deployed a simple ERC721-compatible contract to the Polygon network:

```
contract MyContract is ERC721 {
    uint256 public counter;
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC721(name, symbol) {
        // ...
        counter = 0;
    }
    function myMethod(string memory _arg) public {
        // ...
        counter++;
    }
}
```

My only interaction with the contract is to simply fetch the value of `counter` and then call the `myMethod()`, all in a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  const counter = (await contract.counter()).toNumber();
  console.log(`counter: ${counter}`);
  // ..
  const tx = await contract.connect(myAccount).myMethod(str);
  await tx.wait();
}
```

It's all fine; but *sometimes an old value of the "counter" is retrieved*, for example:

```
counter: 11                     counter: 96
counter: 12                     counter: 97
counter: 13                     counter: 98
counter: 14                     counter: 60  <---- ??!!
counter: 15                     counter: 100 ** corrected in the next iteration
counter: 12  <---- ??!!
counter: 17  ** corrected in the next iteration
```

Why is that? How should I avoid it?!

It's worth noting: in the subsequent iterations, as per the example above, the `counter` is retrieved correctly and holds the most up-to-date value.

Comment: Hm.  I couldn't replicate the issue using your code at least on a local hardhat node.  Ran it several times, it always produced the expected counter order.  Not much help, sorry.

Comment: @GGizmos Actually, I've encountered with the issue even several more times since of the posting.

Comment: @goodUser Where are you running the example? node, browser, ..., which version are you testing against?

Comment: @Ismael I'm simply using HardHat v2.8.4 in NodeJs talking to the Polygon mainnet through `https://polygon-rpc.com/`.